# One drive and Office 365 under Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, microsoft-word

i am working on a Linux Mint 20.3 Una.
I have just changed to Linux due to problems while doing C++ stuff.

A nice to have would be One Drive or the Office Products. Libre is fine, but since i am a student and my University want's all the Stuff in Powerpoint, Excel and Word (sometimes Latex) - this would be really nice.

Jens

Comment: Note that you can create the presentations in Impress and saved them in a format Powerpoint can read. Same with the spreadsheets and documents.

Comment: This is not a wishlist: What did you try, and what was the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office is not supported on Linux officially, but you can still run it with tools like Wine and PlayOnLinux. There are multiple tutorials online on how to do this, and it works just fine. OneDrive is not supported too. There are some paid solutions that work with OneDrive on Linux, but I'm not going to market them.